# Where does the additional indentation in the lstlisting environment come from?

Tags: listings, indentation, code

I would like to document a function from OpenCV. I used the `lstlisting` environment from `listings` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
double cv::calibrateCamera 
(   
    InputArrayOfArrays  objectPoints,
    InputArrayOfArrays  imagePoints,
    Size                imageSize,
    InputOutputArray    cameraMatrix,
    InputOutputArray    distCoeffs,
    OutputArrayOfArrays rvecs,
    OutputArrayOfArrays tvecs,
    int                 flags,
    TermCriteria        criteria
)   
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The above code was formatted using tabs, as can be seen in the following screenshot that shows them as grey arrows:

[image]

As can be seen, the parameter names (that's the second "column": `objectPoints`, `imagePoints`, etc.) all line up nicely.

In the result however, additional white space is introduced:

[image: result]

How can I fix this so that the code is rendered verbatim?

Answer (score 1):

As posted the code produces

[image]

I would guess your original source has tabs not spaces (this site replaces tabs by spaces)

Comment: The problem was indeed related to tabs. I added an answer. However, given that the MWE is rather useless, given that it doesn't reproduce the problem as you point out, should I delete my question? Or should I edit my question to state that tabs were used for the formatting?

Comment: no I'd leave it helps other people with same issue (It's possibly a duplicate though I'll look...)

Answer (score 0):

Well, PEBCAC.

If the text should be rendered verbatim, then it must be ensured that tabs are rendered equally.

As it turns out, `listings` has a few settings, which can be set with this command:

```
\lstset{
    tabsize=4
}
```

**The default value for `tabsize` is 8** and in my **text editor, the size was 4**. With the above setting of 4, the code renders just fine.